# ik looks like inside foreach my code goes into if and else statement in each loop

Tags: php, foreach

I am making a request to my db when I get event of the last 7 days.
Then I'd like to check if for some days of this last week, I did not had entries so I can but a good array of data with ' ' if no input and the correct data if data were entered.

Let's say I have the seven last days :

```
[27,26,25,24,23,22,21];
```

Then if my date in db is not equal to one of the date in these array, in my array result I will put `' '`;
So in my example , I do not have entry for 24 and 23 so I'd like to have :

```
[data, data, data,'','',data,data];
```

So I have tried this code :

```
while($matinal = mysqli_fetch_object($get_matinal)) {

    foreach($lab as $key => $l):

            if (convertDateYmd($matinal->created_at) === $l ) {

                $matinal_result[$key] = $matinal->moyenne_fatigue;

            } else{

            }
    endforeach;
}
```

So basically $get_matinal is my query and got 5 values (5 entries in last week).

$lab is an array with 7 dates : [21,22,23,24,25,26,27];

So what I am trying to do is each time I read the first value of my query => `$get_matinal`, I am running a `foreach` loop to check if the date of this lines is present in my `$lab` array. If yes I'd like to keep the value if not, I'd like to have an empty string if the result.

But with my code, it looks like I enter everytime in the else... of I delete the else, I still have 5 true answer.

So my array $matinal_result should be = `[data,data,data,'','',data,data]` or I get `['','','','','','','']` ...

Comment: why are you not passing $lab to the query to get the data? surly your not querying everything.. do you expect it to perform well with 100k rows just to pick out 7 rows?

Comment: My bad the output is 7 values

Comment: How can I pass $lab to the query ? If possible it would be lot of easier than my tricky solution..

Comment: see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d28bd/10/0